# How to bind multiple menu list from database using mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

i have 3 tables in database country ,state and district tables
initially am able to bind country list in my page,
if i click country i want show related states based on country id in another div same view page
like list (not in dropdownlist)
then if i click state i want to bind related districts based on state id
i have tried

```
public ActionResult  Country()
{
    //created view model to return multiple models to view
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
   _countryAPI = new CountryAPI();
    var country = _countryAPI.GetAll();
    vm.countryViewModel = country.ToList();
    return View(vm);
}

public JsonResult GetStates(int countryID)
{
    ViewModel vm1 = new ViewModel();
    _stateAPI = new StateAPI();
    var states= _stateAPI .GetAll(countryID);
    vm1.statesViewModel = states.ToList();
    return Json(vm1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

view

```
@using Sample.ViewModel
@model Sample.ViewModel

<h4>countries</h4>
@if (Model.countryViewModel != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.countryViewModel)
    {
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-default">
                <li class="">
                    <a id="@item.CID" onclick="stateClick(this)" >@item.CName</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div></div>
}
<h4>States</h4>
@if (Model.statesViewModel != null)
{
    foreach (var item1 in Model.statesViewModel)
    {
        <div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a id="@item1.SID" onclick="districtClick(this)">@item1.SName</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div>no states</div>
}
```

script

```
function stateClick(el) {
    var countryID= $(el).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetStates',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { countryID: countryID },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

am able to bind list of countries and when I click country am getting country id and list but json result
not returning to view, json result returning view model and no result binding in view

Comment: What do you mean _json result returning view model_? Are you getting an error? And all you doing is outputting the result to the console - your not updating the DOM with the results

Comment: And why in the world are you returning your view model in the `GetStates()` method when all you seem to be wanting is the `SID` and `Name` properties of each `State`